# array is not acting like an array and i don't know what to do

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django, authentication, django-rest-framework

I am making a react application with django backend. So for protected routes i am doing something like this.

```
<Route element={<RequireAuth allowedRoles={['admin']}/>}>
            <Route path='admin' element={<Admin />} />
          </Route>
```

And in RequireAuth.js I have this:

```
const RequireAuth = (allowedRoles) => {  
    
    const location = useLocation()

    
    const userdata= JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user')) || {}  

    return (
        (allowedRoles.includes(userdata.user.role))  
            ? <Outlet />
            : userdata?.token 
            ?  <Navigate to='/unauthorized'  state={{ from: location }} replace />
            
            :<Navigate to='/login' state={{ from: location }} replace />  

    )
}
```

Doing this also causes the same error, how do I use props in react if not like this :(
`(allowedRoles.includes(localStorage.getItem('user.role')))`

With some help from a youtube tutorial by Dave Gray, as his method wasn't working, i just opted to use local storage cause i am getting tired but even using local storage, i get the same error

allowedRoles.includes is not a function
TypeError: allowedRoles.includes is not a function

But allowedRoles is an array I think, I had this
`<Route element={<RequireAuth allowedRoles='[admin]'/>}>`
didn't work so I did this
`<Route element={<RequireAuth allowedRoles={['admin']}/>}>`
still No.

In my login I am storing the userdata response as

```
const response = await axios.post(`http://localhost:8000/login/`, JSON.stringify({ email, password }),{headers:{"Content-Type":"application/json"}})
            console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data))
            localStorage.setItem('user',JSON.stringify(response.data) || [])
```

This is the console log:
{"token":"2a4d51f5f7132564115e89310487115ba4138c46","user":{"id":1,"email":"admin@admin.com","first_name":"admin","last_name":"admin","role":"admin"}}

I am using the basic Token of django and sending the userdata along with it .
How do I solve this and Is there a better way to handle the user informations on frontend since In future I want to make a UserProfile page that will let them edit there information.

Comment: Many ways to check the type of `allowedRoles`. `console.log(allowedRoles.constructor)`, `console.log(allowedRoles instanceof Array)`

Comment: Where do i log this since I am being sent to homepage when i log in and RequireAuth.js doesnot seem to be working at all because atleast i should be redirected to login right?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is how you're passing props here:

```
<Route element={<RequireAuth allowedRoles={['admin']}/>}>
   <Route path='admin' element={<Admin />} />
</Route>

const RequireAuth = (allowedRoles) => {  
    ...
}
```

The parameter `allowedRoles` being used in the `RequireAuth` functional component is really the `props` object. You'd need to destructure it if you want to use it as simply allowedRoles. Or you could pass it as props and manually call it where needed as `props.allowedRoles`.

So you could use either of these approaches:

```
<Route element={<RequireAuth allowedRoles={['admin']}/>}>
   <Route path='admin' element={<Admin />} />
</Route>

const RequireAuth = (props) => {  
    console.log(props.allowedRoles)
}

const RequireAuth = ({allowedRoles}) => {  
    console.log(allowedRoles)
}
```

Comment: so I didn't know how to use props lol.

Comment: well, now you know